# Picking random from an assoctive array

Tags: php, arrays

Im making a blackjack game in PHP. So i made an Assoctive array with all the cardnames and values. That looks like this:

```
$cards = array("Schoppen 2"=>"2", "Schoppen 3"=>"3", "Schoppen 4"=>"4", "Schoppen 5"=>"5", "Schoppen 6"=>"6", "Schoppen 7"=>"7", "Schoppen 8"=>"8", "Schoppen 9"=>"9", "Schoppen 10"=>"10"
            , "Schoppen boer"=>"10", "Schoppen vrouw"=>"10", "Schoppen heer"=>"10", "Schoppen aas"=>"11", "Harten 2"=>"2", "Harten 3"=>"3", "Harten 4"=>"4", "Harten 5"=>"5", "Harten 6"=>"6", "Harten 7"=>"7", "Harten 8"=>"8", "Harten 9"=>"9", "Harten 10"=>"10"
            , "Harten boer"=>"10", "Harten vrouw"=>"10", "Harten heer"=>"10", "Harten aas"=>"11", "Klaveren 2"=>"2", "Klaveren 3"=>"3", "Klaveren 4"=>"4", "Klaveren 5"=>"5", "Klaveren 6"=>"6", "Klaveren 7"=>"7", "Klaveren 8"=>"8", "Klaveren 9"=>"9", "Klaveren 10"=>"10"
            , "Klaveren boer"=>"10", "Klaveren vrouw"=>"10", "Klaveren heer"=>"10", "Klaveren aas"=>"11", "Ruiten 2"=>"2", "Ruiten 3"=>"3", "Ruiten 4"=>"4", "Ruiten 5"=>"5", "Ruiten 6"=>"6", "Ruiten 7"=>"7", "Ruiten 8"=>"8", "Ruiten 9"=>"9", "Ruiten 10"=>"10"
            , "Ruiten boer"=>"10", "Ruiten vrouw"=>"10", "Ruiten heer"=>"10", "Ruiten aas"=>"11");
```

Now i want to pick 2 cards for the player and 2 cards for the dealer, so im using this:

`$playercards = array_rand($cards, 2);`
`$dealercards = array_rand($cards, 2);`

But now if i echo `$playercards` its empty. Someone sees the problem? Since i dont worked before with array_rand.

Also the cards may not be the same. So once one is picked he cant be picked again by array_rand, is there an opportunity to fix that too?

Thanks !

Comment: `print_r($playercards);`;  `$playercards` is an array so you can't use echo

Comment: Ah too bad, that works. But now i also want to now the value. So i can use it in blackjack, is there also a way for doing that?

Comment: You can access it as a normal array, see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php (e.g. `echo $playercards[0];`)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're playing cards, why don't you use the [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function?

```
shuffle( $cards );
$card_player_1 = array_shift( $cards );
$card_player_2 = array_shift( $cards );
$card_dealer_1 = array_shift( $cards );
$card_dealer_2 = array_shift( $cards );
```

Those cards will be out of the array thanks to [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

**Update**

if you want to keep the keys, there's a post in the documentation that explains how to achieve it:

> Shuffle associative and non-associative array while preserving key,
>   value pairs. Also returns the shuffled array instead of shuffling it
>   in place.

```
function shuffle_assoc($list) { 
  if (!is_array($list)) return $list; 

  $keys = array_keys($list); 
  shuffle($keys); 
  $random = array(); 
  foreach ($keys as $key) { 
    $random[$key] = $list[$key]; 
  }
  return $random; 
}
```

Then your code:

```
$cards_shuffled = shuffle_assoc( $cards );
$card_player_1 = array_shift( $cards_shuffled);
$card_player_2 = array_shift( $cards_shuffled );
$card_dealer_1 = array_shift( $cards_shuffled );
$card_dealer_2 = array_shift( $cards_shuffled );
```

If you want to store key and value in different variables, you can use this approach:

```
$cards_shuffled = shuffle_assoc($cards);
list($card_player_1_key, $card_player_1_value) = each($cards_shuffled);
array_shift($cards_shuffled);
list($card_player_2_key, $card_player_2_value) = each($cards_shuffled);
array_shift($cards_shuffled);
list($card_dealer_1_key, $card_dealer_1_value) = each($cards_shuffled);
array_shift($cards_shuffled);
list($card_dealer_2_key, $card_dealer_2_value) = each($cards_shuffled);
array_shift($cards_shuffled);

echo $card_player_1_key;// Print key of player 1 card.
echo $card_player_1_value;// Print value of player 1 card.
echo $card_dealer_2_key;// Print key of dealer second card.
```

Comment: That works, but i only get the value then, i also want the name. To show the cards on the screen. Is there any way? So i get the value of the card and the name of the card in vars? Like $nameplayercard1 = and $valueplayercard1 =

Comment: echo $card_player_1; Just gives a value still no name?

Comment: @user3160026 ok, you can get keys and values the way I show you in the new code (last piece of it), hope it helps